# How to get user interaction events in playground with Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode6, swift-playground

I'm trying to prototype a game with `SpriteKit` with `Swift` in a `playground`.

I'm having difficulties getting the user touch callbacks to work.

Here's what I am trying :

```
let view:SKView = SKView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 586))
XCPShowView("Live view", view)

class PrototypeScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func touchesBeganWithEvent(event: NSEvent!)
    {
        println("Hello touches")   
    }
}

let scene:PrototypeScene = PrototypeScene(size: CGSizeMake(320, 586))
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFit

view.presentScene(scene)
```

I'm not getting the callbacks for the responder chain. 
How would one enable this?

Comment: Not an answer because I can't remember for sure, but I think in the swift playgrounds WWDC video they said there wasn't any user interaction possible.

Answer (score 4):

User interaction is not available in Playgrounds (Source: WWDC).

Comment: do you remember which session this was mentioned in?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34519599/524236) for the session reference.

Comment: Playground interaction is available now, starting with Xcode 7.3.

Answer (score 0):

User interactions in Playground are not available in Xcode 7.2 and below