# Mouse events (NSTrackingArea) in Playground not working

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

I have a a subclass of NSView which contains the following NSTrackingArea code. But for some reason the mouse events won't trigger in Playground.

The `viewWillMoveToWindow`is being called, but nothing else seems to fire. Does anyone have a clue to what is missing?

```
class MyView: NSView {

    private var trackingArea: NSTrackingArea    = NSTrackingArea()

    // Other stuff omitted here...
    // ...

    override func viewWillMoveToWindow(newWindow: NSWindow?) {

        // Setup a new tracking area when the view is added to the window.
         trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: self.bounds, options: [.MouseEnteredAndExited, .ActiveAlways], owner: self, userInfo: nil)
         self.addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
    }
    override func updateTrackingAreas() {

          self.removeTrackingArea(trackingArea)

          trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: self.bounds, options: [.MouseEnteredAndExited, .ActiveAlways], owner: self, userInfo: nil)
          self.addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
    }

    // Mouse events
    override func mouseEntered(theEvent: NSEvent) {

         NSLog("MouseEntered")
    }
     override func mouseExited(theEvent: NSEvent) {

         NSLog("MouseExited")
    }
     override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {

         NSLog("MouseDown")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you test it with a real project? Or try import XCPlayground
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

Comment: I know it works in a real project, but wanted to use Playground to test a few things with drawing. `XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true` didn't do the trick. XCPlayground was already imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/408) 2014 WWDC session:

> There are few more limitations with Playgrounds.
>   Playgrounds cannot be used for things which require user interaction.
>   So we have great support for showing live views but you can only see them, you can't touch them.

You can find the original video [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-408/)

Comment: This confirms my suspicion. Thanks for digging that up :-)

Comment: Seems this is now possible since Xcode 7.3 beta: http://ericasadun.com/2016/01/26/xcode-7-3-beta-2-introduces-live-interactive-playgrounds/